# Tabulator custom key bindings with .extendModule()

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to bind a custom keys combination to perform a custom action like below but the key binding is not working. I even tried adding `keybindings: true` in the `init` settings but no change. There are no errors, warnings or notices in the console whatsoever.

I'm really not sure whether I'm using the `.extendModule()` correctly, though I have checked [the docs](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/modules#module-keybindings) already.

```js
var rowContextMenu = function(e, row) {
 // do something here
 console.log("RIGHT CLICK: Context menu triggered");
}

var deleteRow = function(row) {
 let rData = row.getData();

 if(rData.hasOwnProperty('_children')) {
  let cRows = row.getTreeChildren();
  $.each(cRows, function() {
   let r = this;

   setTimeout(function() {
    deleteRow(r);
   }, 0);
  });
 }

 row.delete();
};

Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("keybindings", "actions", {
 "deleteSelectedRows":function(){ //delete selected rows
  let selectedRows = this.table.getSelectedRows();

  selectedRows.forEach(function(row){
   deleteRow(row);
  });
  console.log('ROWS DELETED: Triggered with button keyboard');
 },
});

Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("keybindings", "bindings", {
 deleteSelectedRows:"shift + 9",
});

let nestedData = [
 {name:"Oli Bob", location:"United Kingdom", gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", _children:[
  {name:"Mary May", location:"Germany", gender:"female", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
  {name:"Christine Lobowski", location:"France", gender:"female", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
  {name:"Brendon Philips", location:"USA", gender:"male", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980", _children:[
   {name:"Margret Marmajuke", location:"Canada", gender:"female", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
   {name:"Frank Harbours", location:"Russia", gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966"},
  ]},
 ]},
 {name:"Jamie Newhart", location:"India", gender:"male", col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985"},
 {name:"Gemma Jane", location:"China", gender:"female", col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982", _children:[
  {name:"Emily Sykes", location:"South Korea", gender:"female", col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970"},
 ]},
 {name:"James Newman", location:"Japan", gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998"},
];

let table = new Tabulator('#my-tabulator', {
 height:"400px",
 layout:"fitColumns",
 data: nestedData,
 /**
  * // Actual ajax configuration that won't work with test data (works perfectly with live data)
  * 
  * ajaxLoaderLoading:'<div class="text-center" style="display:inline-block;"><img style="width:100px;" src="/path/to/my/spinner.svg"></div>',
  * ajaxURL:"/path/to/my/data.json", //ajax URL
  * ajaxConfig:"get", //ajax HTTP request type
  */
 sortable: false,
 selectable:true, //make rows selectable
 dataTree:true,
 dataTreeChildIndent:24,
 dataTreeStartExpanded:[true, false], //start with first level expanded, second level collapsed
 dataTreeCollapseElement:"<span class='expand-collpase-btn'>-</span>",
 dataTreeExpandElement:"<span class='expand-collpase-btn'>+</span>",
 rowFormatter:function(row){
  if(row.getData().parent_id === null){
   row.getElement().classList.add("root-node");
  }
 },
 keybindings: {
  deleteSelectedRows:"shift + 9"
 },
 rowContext:rowContextMenu,
 columnMinWidth : 24,
 columns:[
  {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, responsive:0}, //never hide this column
  {title:"Location", field:"location", width:150},
  {title:"Gender", field:"gender", width:150, responsive:2}, //hide this column first
  {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", width:150},
  {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center", sorter:"date", width:150},
 ],
 /**
  * // Actual column configuration that won't work with test data (works perfectly with live data)
  * 
  * columns:[
  *  {title:"Col 1", field:"field_1", headerSort:false, titleFormatter:headerFilter, titleFormatterParams:filters, responsive:0,
  *   formatter:function(cell, formatterParams){
  *    //cell - the cell component
  *    //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
  * 
  *    let rowData = cell.getRow().getData();
  * 
  *    if(rowData['test'] == 'String 1' || rowData['test'] === false) {
  *     let cellUrl = $('<a></a>', {href: '/path/to/cell/item/itemid:'+rowData['id'], target: "_blank"}).html(cell.getValue());
  *     return cellUrl[0];
  *    }
  *    return cell.getValue(); //return the contents of the cell;
  *   }, 
  *  },
  *  {title:"Col 2", field:"field_2", headerSort:false, width:150,
  *   formatter:function(cell, formatterParams){
  *    //cell - the cell component
  *    //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
  * 
  *    let rowData = cell.getRow().getData();
  * 
  *    if(rowData['test']) {
  *     return '<span class="text-muted text-bold text-italic">String 1</span>';
  *    }
  *    return '<span class="text-italic">String 2</span>';
  *   },
  *  },
  *  {title:"Col 3", headerSort:false, field:"field_3", width:200, align:"right", titleFormatter:headerFilter, titleFormatterParams:filters, responsive:2}, //hide this column first
  *  {title:"Col 4", headerSort:false, field:"field_4", width:200, align:"right", titleFormatter:headerFilter, titleFormatterParams:filters},
  *  {
  *   title:"", 
  *   headerSort:false,
  *   resizable: false,
  *   columns: [
  *    {title:"", width:24, headerSort:false, resizable: false, formatter:editButton, cssClass:'table-actions'},
  *    {title:"", width:24, headerSort:false, resizable: false, formatter:deleteButton, cssClass:'table-actions'},
  *   ]
  *  },
  * ]
  */
});

$('#delete-rows-btn').on('click', function(e){
 let selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();

 selectedRows.forEach(function(row){
  deleteRow(row);
 });
 console.log('ROWS DELETED: Triggered with button click');
});

$('#reload-table-btn').on('click', function(e){
 console.log('Table reloaded');
 table.replaceData(nestedData);
});
```

```css
/**
 * I'm using custom CSS
 * but let's ignore it for the sake of this demo
 */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<a id="delete-rows-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete Selected</a>
&emsp;
<a id="reload-table-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Reload Table</a>
<div id="my-tabulator" class="table-bordered"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `shift + keyCode`and disable rowSelectable. My code works if you

1. focus on table
2. press ***Shift + 9*** Key

```js
  var rowContextMenu = function (e, row) {
    // do something here
    console.log("RIGHT CLICK: Context menu triggered");
  }

  var deleteRow = function (row) {
    let rData = row.getData();

    if (rData.hasOwnProperty('_children')) {
      let cRows = row.getTreeChildren();
      $.each(cRows, function () {
        let r = this;

        setTimeout(function () {
          deleteRow(r);
        }, 0);
      });
    }

    row.delete();
  };

  Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("keybindings", "actions", {
    "deleteSelectedRows": function () { //delete selected rows
      let selectedRows = this.table.getSelectedRows();

      selectedRows.forEach(function (row) {
        deleteRow(row);
      });
      console.log('ROWS DELETED: Triggered with button keyboard');
    },
  });

  Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("keybindings", "bindings", {
    deleteSelectedRows: "shift + 9",
  });

  let nestedData = [
    {
      name: "Oli Bob", location: "United Kingdom", gender: "male", col: "red", dob: "14/04/1984", _children: [
        {name: "Mary May", location: "Germany", gender: "female", col: "blue", dob: "14/05/1982"},
        {name: "Christine Lobowski", location: "France", gender: "female", col: "green", dob: "22/05/1982"},
        {
          name: "Brendon Philips", location: "USA", gender: "male", col: "orange", dob: "01/08/1980", _children: [
            {name: "Margret Marmajuke", location: "Canada", gender: "female", col: "yellow", dob: "31/01/1999"},
            {name: "Frank Harbours", location: "Russia", gender: "male", col: "red", dob: "12/05/1966"},
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {name: "Jamie Newhart", location: "India", gender: "male", col: "green", dob: "14/05/1985"},
    {
      name: "Gemma Jane", location: "China", gender: "female", col: "red", dob: "22/05/1982", _children: [
        {name: "Emily Sykes", location: "South Korea", gender: "female", col: "maroon", dob: "11/11/1970"},
      ]
    },
    {name: "James Newman", location: "Japan", gender: "male", col: "red", dob: "22/03/1998"},
  ];

  let table = new Tabulator('#my-tabulator', {
    height: "400px",
    layout: "fitColumns",
    data: nestedData,
    sortable: false,
    // selectable: true, //make rows selectable
    dataTree: true,
    dataTreeChildIndent: 24,
    dataTreeStartExpanded: [true, false], //start with first level expanded, second level collapsed
    dataTreeCollapseElement: "<span class='expand-collpase-btn'>-</span>",
    dataTreeExpandElement: "<span class='expand-collpase-btn'>+</span>",
    rowFormatter: function (row) {
      if (row.getData().parent_id === null) {
        row.getElement().classList.add("root-node");
      }
    },
    keybindings: {
      deleteSelectedRows: "shift + 57"
    },
    rowContext: rowContextMenu,
    columnMinWidth: 24,
    columns: [
      {title: "Name", field: "name", width: 200, responsive: 0}, //never hide this column
      {title: "Location", field: "location", width: 150},
      {title: "Gender", field: "gender", width: 150, responsive: 2}, //hide this column first
      {title: "Favourite Color", field: "col", width: 150},
      {title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob", align: "center", sorter: "date", width: 150},
    ],

  });

  $('#delete-rows-btn').on('click', function (e) {
    let selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();

    selectedRows.forEach(function (row) {
      deleteRow(row);
    });
    console.log('ROWS DELETED: Triggered with button click');
  });

  $('#reload-table-btn').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('Table reloaded');
    table.replaceData(nestedData);
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<a id="delete-rows-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete Selected</a>
&emsp;
<a id="reload-table-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Reload Table</a>
<div id="my-tabulator" class="table-bordered"></div>
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately, there's no point if I can't select a row because I want to delete selected rows using key bindings

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr This question is answered, if you have another requirement Add a check box on first column select that instead of a row and delete it row has key bindings like edit undo etc.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see if it works. **Row has left bindings like edit undo etc.** Can you point me to the documentation please. The example given in documentation (linked in question) is about deleting selected rows like I'm trying but it doesn't work. See here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/modules#module-keybindings

Comment: I'm sorry for not being precise. I meant documentation where it says row delete can't be done the way I'm attempting

Comment: I am telling you that as per best of my knowledge, It is not in Documentation maybe you can Raise a bug or feature request on Github page